# Customize Page builder Slider with react

Tags: magento2, slider, page-builder, react

I am trying to create a slider-slick with react like this one:

[image]

But in magento page builder they have ContentTypes inside node_modules, and how can I customize it with my own components? or How can I override it ?

Here is my slider from page builder:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think following examples may help you to understand how to create new or customize exists Page Builder types

[Page Builder Examples](https://github.com/magento-devdocs/pagebuilder-examples)

Comment: Can we customize react-slick inside /node_modules/@magento/pagebuilder/Slider?

Comment: Not sure I understand a question. See example how to customize slider component type https://github.com/magento-devdocs/pagebuilder-examples/tree/master/Slider/Extension. You can customize component-type renderer and template to render required content using any library.